# I'm trying to send a request through Relay.injectNetworkLayer() to a java server

Tags: java, reactjs, webpack, graphql, relayjs

I have:

```
 ChildItem = Relay.createContainer(ChildItem , {
 fragments: {
 childItem: () => Relay.QL`
   fragment on Item
  {
    name
    color
  }`
}});

 ItemList = Relay.createContainer(ItemList, {
 fragments: {
 list: () => Relay.QL `
   fragment on Item{
     id
     ${ChildItem.getFragment('childItem')}
   }`
}});
```

Using React.injectNetworkLayer() I send a request to the back-end server where I'm trying to receive the result of the GraphQL query which looks like this:

```
 {"query":"query GraphQLObjQueryType {
    GraphQLObj_query {
    ...F1
    }
 }
   fragment F0 on GraphQLObj 
   {
     name,
     color {
         id
     },
     id
      }
     fragment F1 on GraphQLObj  {
         id,
          ...F0
     }",
"variables":{}}
```

GraphQLObjQueryType is a GraphQLObjectType(query) with name field GraphQLObj_query of the object GraphQLObj.

Is there a additional setting for relay or GraphQL that tells how  the response should be sent.

Comment: Are you already using graphql-java for your server? Apparently, they have [basic Relay support](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java#relay-support).

Comment: Hello, @marktani ! Yes, I implemented graphql-java on my server.